# About Weibel Exercise 1.1.5, how can we give an argument $3\implies 1$ without use $2$?

Tags: homology-cohomology

[image]

I can give an argument of "$3\implies 1$" as:

Since $H_n(0)\to H_n(C.)$ is an isomorphism, and $H_n(0)=0$, then $H_n(C.)=0$, and which means $Z_n(C.)=B_n(C.)$ by the definition of quotient module, namely $C.$ is exact at $C_n$.

However, this seems to be ugly, because my argument is through $2.$ in fact. And my question is, how can I give a "direct" proof?

Comment: You can't be more direct than what you did. The thing is, property $(2)$ is the *definition* of property $(3)$ (or is close enough to be basically indistinguishable from the definition), so any argument will automatically have to go through $(2)$.

Comment: @CaptainLama I see. thx.